# PHP output returning a tab space before write file

Tags: php, output, archive, fputcsv

in this code I start with header to create a csv file:

```
    $cabecalho = array(
    "RazaoSocial",
    "NomeFantasia",
    "Nome",
    "CNPJ",
    "CPF",
    "Telefone",
    "E-Mail"
);
$cliente = array(
    "RazaoSocial" => "1",
    "NomeFantasia" => "2",
    "Nome" => "3",
    "CNPJ" => "4",
    "CPF" => "5",
    "Telefone" => "6",
    "EMail" => "7"
);

$clientes[] = $cliente;
/* Criando nome para o arquivo */
$filename = sprintf('lala_%s.csv', date('Y-m-d H-i'));


/* Definindo header de saída */
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8", true);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');


fputcsv($fp, $cabecalho, ";");
foreach ($clientes as $val){
    fputcsv($fp, $val, ";");
}

fclose($fp);
exit();
```

when i save the file, returning a white space in init of archive, I don't have any idea. (img link);

[image of archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD4He.png)

anyone has idea?

Comment: Does your PHP file contain any whitespaces or tabs before the starting `<?php` or in some include files?

Comment: Is a extensive project, have a lot of includes and uses in code. That code is for export a table of clients list. Already indicated me the same thing, but i am in that for 3 hours trying to find here is the whitespace before a <?php tag

Comment: have a way to remove spaces before <?php ?

Comment: Yes, find and edit the files that have such spaces ;) Or don't use `php://output`

Comment: I will try to find that kkk. Have a way to create a new static file with php://output?

Comment: Why do you need to create a file (through output) anyways? Why not directly `echo` the stuff? But after all, changing only this one part does not remove the spaces from other files

Comment: If your file includes other files, the tab character can be, as well, after a closing `?>` tag. The closing `?>` PHP tag can be safely removed if there is no content after it in the file. As a general rule, it's recommended to not mix code with content in the same file.

Comment: I just not find the white spaces. Now i trying to clean buffer to echo values in archive and send the file, using ob_clean, ob_start. But not works;

Comment: Well, don't have any way to reset header to init a new strem to create a fopen file

Comment: Please remove "solved" from your title and move your solution to its own answer. Thank you.

Comment: I new here. How I move my solution for me own answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution**:

Create a temp file to write the data, create a new header, end buffer with not send the request, flush the archive and after all uses delete the temp file:

```
    define("PULAR_LINHA", "\n");
define("DELIMITAR_COLUNA", ";");

    function writeArchive($fileName = "archive", $cabecalho = null, $valores = null){

    $filename = sprintf($fileName.'_%s.csv', date('Y-m-d H-i'));

    $tmpName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'data');
    $file = fopen($tmpName, 'w');

    fputcsv($file, $cabecalho, DELIMITAR_COLUNA);
    foreach ($valores as $val){
        fputcsv($file, $val, DELIMITAR_COLUNA);
    }       
    fclose($file);

    /* Abre uma chamada especifica somente para este arquivo temp */
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.csv');
    ob_end_clean(); //finalizar buffer sem enviar
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpName));

    ob_clean();//finalizar buffer
    flush(); //descarregar o buffer acumulado
    readfile($tmpName); //ler arquivo/enviar
    unlink($tmpName); //deletar arquivo temporario
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my output file always starting with a tab space.

The solution was much simpler, I added

```php
ob_end_clean();
```

code before the header(); and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

please try to save this csv file on disk and once saved then you may download direct this file or redirect

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/newfile.csv');
```

Also you will find the actual issue while you will work on saving this file to disk.

Comment: I needed to use the described answer above because the code is too legacy and used a lot of different IDE and will be very hard to found all the empty lines or white spaces. Then I created the function above to create from scratch a new csv file.